# Mongo CP, Cassandra AP?

Tags: mongodb, partitioning, high-availability, cassandra, consistency

I have read lot of articles on net but still confused why  Mongo  CP, Cassandra AP,  RDBMS CA ?
Will explain my understanding and query along with that .

**Mongo**

Consider a scenario where I have one master  ans two slaves.  consider

1. Write request arrives and goes to master.
2. It gets committed on master only but master goes off(crashed) before it is written to slaves
3. Till master is re-elected, write requests need to wait and system is not available
4. Once the previous node(node crashed in step 2) comes back, writes pending from that node are written back to slaves. This is called
   eventual consistency.

Per my understanding because of step 3 and 4, Mongo is said to be CP where C stands for eventual consistent. Correct ?

**Cassandra**

Here  there is no master/slave model and every node takes its share write and read request based on shard key.

1. Write request arrives to any node(called coordination node).
2. Coordination node redirects to one of the node based on shard key
3. It gets committed  but node goes off(crashed) before it is written to other replication node.
4. Again write request with same shard key, now coordinated node redirect it immediately to replica node(replica of crashed node)
5. Once the previous node(node crashed in step 3) comes back, writes pending from that node are written back to replica node. So cassandra seems
   to be eventual consistent too ?

Step 4 explains why cassandra is highly available but step 5 also depicts its eventual consistent. So Per my undsertanding , cassandra provides
provides both eventual consistency ans availability. Then why it is said it does not provide Consitency ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> C stands for eventual consistent. Correct ?

*Consistency* in the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) is referring to **strong** consistency where every read receives the most recent write or an error. By default MongoDB drivers direct all reads & writes to the primary of a replica set, which is strongly consistent.

The CAP theorem asserts that a distributed system must choose between consistency and availability in the event of a network partition. MongoDB's replica set approach uses a single primary for write consistency (CP), while Cassandra's replication strategy favours write availability (AP). Strong consistency is not possible with a network partition because there could be a conflict if both sides of the partition update the same data. To maintain write availability AP database systems need a solution for [conflict resolution](https://dzone.com/articles/conflict-resolution-using-last-write-wins-vs-crdts), which is a separate consideration from eventual consistency.

However, CAP is a simplification of real-world behaviour: MongoDB and Cassandra both have tunable levels of consistency for reads and writes. For example: MongoDB has [write concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) to determine the level of acknowledgement required for write operations, [read preferences](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) for routing requests to members of a replica set, and [read concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/) to control the recency, consistency, and isolation properties of data read from replica set and sharded deployments.

Eric Brewer, author of the CAP Theorem, revisited this in 2012 with a more nuanced take: [CAP Twelve Years Later: How the "Rules" Have Changed](https://www.infoq.com/articles/cap-twelve-years-later-how-the-rules-have-changed).

> 3. Till master is re-elected, write requests need to wait and system is not available

There are no writes without a primary, but replica sets still have read availability. MongoDB 3.6 added a [Retryable Writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/) feature which helps applications better handle replica set elections and transient network errors.

> 4. Once the previous node(node crashed in step 2) comes back, writes pending from that node are written back to slaves.

If the primary in a MongoDB replica set becomes unavailable, the remaining members of the replica set will elect a new primary if there is an eligible secondary and a quorum of voting members. In your example, the voting majority would be 2/3 members of your replica set. Any writes accepted by a former primary that were not written to a majority of replica set members will be [rolled back](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/) (saved to disk) so the former primary resumes syncing from a state consistent with the history of the current primary.

Comment: When you say `By default MongoDB drivers direct all reads & writes to the primary of a replica set, which is strongly consistent.`
I believe you are referring to master/slave model here or simple replica without master/slave. In case of master/slave,
if  all reads & writes  goes to the primary of a replica set , then slaves does not have any role. Is n't it ?

Comment: Also still I did not get why cassandra is said to be available but not consistent ? Can you please elaborate it .

Comment: @user3198603 I'm specifically referring to MongoDB replica sets and not the deprecated master/slave topology. The main goals for replica sets are data redundancy and failover. You can also read from secondaries, but in the context of CAP theorem that will not provide strong consistency so you would be trading read Consistency for Availability. Similarly, Cassandra is eventually consistent by default and provides Availability rather than Consistency. I think you are missing the context that the C in CAP is for **strong consistency** in the event of a network partition.

Comment: The CAP theorem is about design tradeoffs but is not an absolute classification for all behaviour for a given database system. Although the default configuration may have AP or CP characteristics, it may also be possible to tune the behaviour for your use case. The DataStax architecture guide also has specific mention of tunable consistency to act more like a CP or AP system depending on your application requirements: [How are consistent read and write operations handled?](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntAboutDataConsistency.html).

Comment: Two follow up questions :-
Question1:-You said `I'm specifically referring to MongoDB replica sets and not the deprecated master/slave topology.` Just to reconfirm i believe 
you mean ideally
there will be single node that will be handling all writes and read  whereas replicas will be used as backup(in case primary gets failed new primary/master/slave
is selected and all read/writes will happen from there). In case of Cassandra , there is no primary/master and replica model, all nodes have to perform
read and write based on shard key.

Comment: So even if one node is down, another replica node can be selected which will now take read(may not be consistent) and write 
request. Is that right now ?

Question2:
You said `Similarly, Cassandra is eventually consistent by default and provides Availability rather than Consistency.` Can you please explain with
the example(or with some tweak) I have given in my post, how cassandra is providing Availability rather than Consistency ?

Comment: As per your last comments, Cassandra favours write availability in the event of a network partition which implies eventual consistency since you cannot have strong consistency with multiple independent masters. There is a link in my original answer regarding challenges of [conflict resolution](https://dzone.com/articles/conflict-resolution-using-last-write-wins-vs-crdts) and a link in my previous comment regarding [AP vs CP](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntAboutDataConsistency.html) for Cassandra in particular.

Comment: Thank you Stennie. Can you please confirm if my understanding in first followup question in my last comment is correct i.e. Question1:-You said I'm ..and write request. Is that right now ? It will really help .

Comment: @user3198603 Perhaps this quote from the CAP theorem Wikipedia article will help: "In the presence of a partition, one is then left with two options: consistency or availability. When choosing consistency over availability, the system will return an error or a time-out if particular information cannot be guaranteed to be up to date due to network partitioning. When choosing availability over consistency, the system will always process the query and try to return the most recent available version of the information, even if it cannot guarantee it is up to date due to network partitioning."

Comment: I almost got it. I had specific question which i have posted at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210085/replica-model-in-cassandra-vs-mongo. See if you can provide inputs there ?